# Flask view shows 400 error instead of template with form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to display a page with a form, then add a `Player` to the database when the form is submitted. However, I can't view the form because the browser always shows a `400 Bad Request` error. Other posts indicate that this could be because the name of the form input doesn't match the key I get from `request.form`, but all my keys match. Why do I get this error?

```html
<form method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <input name="name">
    <input name="available">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/addplayer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addplayer():
    connect('basketball_contracts', host='localhost', port=27017)
    n = request.form['name']
    a = request.form['available']
    post= Post(
        name=n,
        available=a
    )
    post.tags = ['test']
    post.save()
    return render_template('addplayer.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view accepts `GET` and `POST` requests. `request.form` is only filled out on `POST`. If you try to access a key that doesn't exist, it raises a 400 error. No keys will exist when you `GET` the page initially.

The common pattern for this is to guard code that requires `request.form` in an `if request.method == 'POST'` block. Return a redirect after handling the `POST` request, otherwise return the rendered template.

```
from flask import url_for, redirect, render_template

@app.route('/addplayer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addplayer():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Post(
            name=request.form['name'],
            available=request.form['available']
        ).save()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('addplayer.html')
```

---

Since you appear to be using Flask-WTF, you can use the form's `validate_on_submit` method instead of checking `method`. In that case, you can also access the data through the form instance, and use the form to render the inputs for you.

```
from flask import url_for, redirect, render_template

@app.route('/addplayer', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addplayer():
    form = AddPlayerForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        Post(
            name=form.name.data,
            available=form.available.data
        ).save()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('addplayer.html', form=form)
```

```html
<form method=post>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label}} {{ form.name }}<br>
    {{ form.available.label }} {{ form.available }}<br>
    <input type=submit value="Add Player">
</form>
```