# "400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'ID-mod'" error while trying to POST to a Flask server with jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, flask

I'm trying to POST with jQuery to a Flask server, but when the data is sent, in Flask debugger occures an error:

> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'ID-mod'

The Flask code:

```py
@app.route('/modify',methods=['POST'])
def modEl():
    print('SOMEHITN',request.form['ID-mod'])
    element = request.form['ID-mod']
    toModIn = request.form['mod']
    elToMod = tasks.query.filter_by(identifier=element).all()
    for el in elToMod:
        el.content=toModIn
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

The jQuery POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/modify',
    data:{"mod":formValue,"ID-mod":id},
    processData:false,
    success:function(){
        location.reload(true)
    }
});
```

"formValue" and "id" are two variables of my app, and they are ok, they are just strings.

I would to get the variables sent from jQuery in the server.
How can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask view shows 400 error instead of template with form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280558/flask-view-shows-400-error-instead-of-template-with-form)

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across this before, but I've done a quick test and it works when you use `request.form.get('ID-mod')`, but not `request.form['ID-mod']`.

If anyone knows why this has different results, please share!

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't worked, the same error occured. Do you have any other solution?