# Returning an input sentence on html with Flask and Python

Tags: python, html, flask, request

I am totally new to Flask, so I am just experimenting for the moment. I simply want to read in a sentence from the user interface and then return the sentence. However, I get the error:

```
BadRequestKeyError(key)
```

My code looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def do_query():
    query = request.form['query']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('/query')
    else:
        return render_template('query.html', query=query)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the query.html is like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body%}
    <form action="/query" method=”POST”>
        <label> Enter your Query Sentence: </label>
        <input type=”text” name=”query” id="query" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Here is your sentence: {{query}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I think the problem might be, that the query variable is not initialized, but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask view shows 400 error instead of template with form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280558/flask-view-shows-400-error-instead-of-template-with-form)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I understand now, that the problem is indeed that there is no request.form() method when the method is not "POST". However, I am still struggling with the implementation. What they used in the post ist using a 'Post( ...).save' command.. I dont really understand what's going on there, also they are not passing a variable to the html in the solution.

Comment: well what do you want the `query` variable to be when the form is first loaded? You have to simply specify something, as there's no form submission to get it from.

Comment: I want to display only the input line on the first load and only after the entry of the query I want to additionally return the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite you route thus:

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def do_query():
    query = request.form['query'] if request.method == 'POST' else ''
    return render_template('query.html', query=query)
```

You will not be trying to access non-existing request data (i.e., `form` data of a non-POST request). This will mean that when you first navigate to the `/query` page, the template will display something like:

```
Here is your sentence:
```

(i.e., no value for `query`)

The wrong request type issue, however, will be gone, as will the redundant redirection. Try to minimize the use of redirection, since they significantly slow down interactions, and hurt the user experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried something similar by initializing `query = ' '`. Unfortunately it ALWAYS returns `' '`, also when I enter a query. It's the same with the code that you have provided. Maybe something is wrong with my html?

Comment: It's a bit hard to relate to you comment, since I do not know whatthe **exact** code is. In my code, the python variable `query` is only assigned to once, either to data from the form (if a POST request) or to a default empty value. As for your HTML, I cannot see any problem with it (I'm also not in an environment where I can reproduce your code, so my advice goes with a grain of salt).

Comment: actually the code that I posted is all that I have for the moment, as I am experimenting on that exact issue. I think the problem is, that when I the assignment when it is a POST request gets overwritten again with `' '`when the html is displayed.

Comment: If you get the chance please help me, it totally drives me crazy why this isn't working I am trying since like 5 hours! :(

Comment: I found the issue: I used the wrong `" "`for `"POST"` and for `name=query"`... I cant believe this actually makes a difference - lesson learned.

Comment: @spadel - Now that you mention it, I am able to see the issue. How did you manage to insert directional double-quotes into a code editor? Anyway, now that you solved the problem, your work is not done, and you need to put this question to rest. That means  providing an answer of your own to the question (a full answer, with corrected code and an explanation of what happened). If you do not do this, please remove the question from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The code didn't work, because I used the wrong quotes in the html file. By default, html chooses the correct quotes and (at least within PyCharm), it is not possible to make any mistakes. However, I copied the html code from a stackoverflow source. Once I fixed that, the answer provided by @Amitai Irron was working :)